# Prove: A complex matrix with a rank of 1 is diagonizable iff its' trace is not $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So far:

The fact that the rank is 1 tells me that there are $n-1$ eigenvectors that are linearly independent with an eigenvalue of $0$. If the matrix is diagonizable, it's similar to a diagonal matrix with a diagonal that has $n-1$ $0$'s and one $a$, corresponding to another eigenvalue. $a!=0$ because if it did, the matrix's kernel's dimension would be $n$ under some basis for the space, contradicting the fact that the rank of the matrix is 1.

As for the other direction, by rank=1 I know that with respect to some basis, the matrix is all $0$'s apart from the first row. The first element in the first row is some $a!=0$, because the trace$!=0$. I'm assuming that I have to show that the rest of the elements in the first row are all $0$'s, but I'm not sure how to.

How do I continue from here? Did I make any mistakes?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix of rank $1$ has the form

$$M = u \cdot v^T$$

with two vectors $u$ and $v$. For that $M$, we have

$$\operatorname{Tr} M = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i\cdot v_i.$$

The kernel of $M$ is the set $$\left\{w \in \mathbb{C}^n : \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\cdot v_i = 0\right\}.$$

So we have

$$u \in \ker M \iff \operatorname{Tr} M  = 0.$$

A basis in which $M$ is diagonal must consist of a multiple of $u$ and a basis of $\ker M$.